# Jinja2 pound symbol £

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I am trying to use the British pound currency symbol in my Jinja2 HTML page.

I can get the dollar symbol to work fine, but when I swap it with the pound, The generated page is blank

```
<tr align="center">
    <td class="col-value">{{ userStats['pendingCommission'] }}</td>
    <td class="col-value">{{ userStats['clearedCommission'] }}</td>
    <td class="col-value">{{  "£{:.2f}".format((userStats['totalCommission'])|float) }}</td>
/tr>
```

Comment: Is there a html relpacement like `&euro;`?

Comment: Did you try putting outside of the `var` ref `{{ ...}}` ? Like, `<td class="col-value">£{{  "{:.2f} ...`

Comment: `&pound;` is probably the quickest way to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign is in ASCII, the pound sign is not, and your editor will save your file in another encoding to support the pound. Make sure that encoding is UTF-8.

Or simply use entities instead of the character.